# Ubuntu Software Center can't connect

Tags: software-center, offline

My connection is fine but when I open the software center, the install button is grey. It says I'm not connected.

I have tried the following:
*Reinstalling, updating and upgrading
*Changing server
*Rebooting computer (yes)

(update screenshot)
https://s29.postimg.org/4jzr6zaef/sample.png

Answer (score 1):

Try doing update via terminal first `sudo apt-get update` then upgrade everything `sudo apt-get upgrade` ,then run `software-center` and try again.

Answer (score 1):

This is years after the fact, but I just came across this same issue, and resolved it with a tip found elsewhere.

In my case, it was resolved by going to terminal and using:

```
sudo apt purge update-manager update-manager-core && sudo apt install update-manager
```

It appears that there have been some updates to Update Manager, and this changed it's network checking behavior.
The only change log entry I could locate for networking was from late 2010 though.